# Woocommerce shipment tax line programmatically

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, filter-woocommerce

In the Netherlands we have different tax rates 9% and 21%.
In my Woocommerce shop I have product with both rates.
For the shipment there is a rule you mus calculate the highest rate if the customer buy a product with this rate (21%). If the customer buy a product with the lower rate (9%) you may calculate 9% on the shipmentcosts.

I created 2 shipment classes for both rates.

Woocommerce has a setting to calculate the most expensive class.
You must fill the price exclusive tax.
This is the wrong calculation for me

- Shipment inclusive tax € 7,50
- Shipment exclusive tax 9% € 6,88
- Shipment exclusive tax 21% € 6,20

If the customer buy a product with 9% and 21% Woocommerce will calculate always the 9% because the exclusive price is the highest.

Is there somebody who know how I can change this to the right way?